# Convert 24 hours time variable into 12Hours time with AngularJS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm getting a value from database which is in 24 hours time string.
I'm looking for a way to change this string in to 12 hours clock time using angularJS or jQuery.

I can not do any code changes to the back-end(JAVA) or database at the moment.

```
var offTime = "17:25:11";
```

I need it to display as : `"5:25:11"`

please help !

Comment: I would recommend [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Me too, and the directive angular-moment : https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: MomentJs is gourgeous and recommended.

Comment: I can not use any additional libraries here guys. only angular and jquery is what I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the value by `:`, the rebuild it after running the first value through the modulo operator. Try this:

```js
var offTime = "17:25:11".split(':');
offTime[0] = offTime[0] % 12;
var output = offTime.join(':');

alert(output);
```

Answer (score 4):

Working off Kabb5's answer I added a bit more logic to determine AM / PM and check for 0 so 0 AM isn't an option.

```
angular.module('simpleAppFilters').filter('twentyFourToTwelve', function () {
return function (inputTime) {        
    inputTime = inputTime.toString(); //value to string for splitting
    var splitTime = inputTime.split(':');
    var ampm = (splitTime[0] >= 12 ? ' PM' : ' AM'); //determine AM or PM 
    splitTime[0] = splitTime[0] % 12;
    splitTime[0] = (splitTime[0] == 0 ? 12 : splitTime[0] ); //adjust for 0 = 12

    return splitTime.join(':') + ampm;
};
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a filter like this:

```
app.filter('twentyFourToTwelve ', function () {
  return function (inputTime) {
    var splitTime = inputTime.split(':');
    splitTime[0] = splitTime[0] % 12;

    return splitTime.join(':');        
  };
});
```

And then in your binding:

```
{{ myTime | twentyFourToTwelve }}
```

Comment: Thanks, another clean solution.