# Angular datetime-local 24hrs format

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, datetime-format

it is possible to use the 24hrs format in the angular input[datetime-local] component? (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdatetime-local%5D)

I could set the timezone to UTC using the ngMOdelOptions but the time keep showing AM/PM

thanks

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with AngularJS; it's using the browser's implementation of [the input type="datetime-local"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html), which doesn't allow for formatting.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately not, thanks for the reply

Answer (score -1):

You can find the answer on [Convert 24 hours time variable into 12Hours time with AngularJS/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849002/convert-24-hours-time-variable-into-12hours-time-with-angularjs-jquery).
You can read more here, [Format Date time in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920892/format-date-time-in-angular-js) and here too, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date.

Comment: „You can find the answer on (…)“ This is site where you are supposed to give an **answer** not **link** to an answer. -1